# How to add a class in jQuery when there is no content inside html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a wordpress/php website in which I want to add a class when there is no content inside the child classes.

Formatted HTML:

```
<div class="featured-block">
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">
            <img class="default-opacity" src="" data-fallback-img="" alt="">
         </figure>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">
            <img class="default-opacity" src="" data-fallback-img="" alt="">
         </figure>
      </div>
   </a>
   <!-- -->
   <a href="/149553/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">  // It should be added here only
            <img src="" srcset="">      
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title"></h1>
            // No content
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"></h1>
            // No content
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
   <!-- -->
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">   
            <img src="" 
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h1>
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Here is the logic which I have used in jQuery but it doesn't seem to work properly as it is adding class everywhere. It should be added at the place where I have commented **// It should be added here only**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ($(".featured-block__title").is(":empty") && $(".featured-block__tag").is(":empty")) {
        $(".img-fit").addClass("opacity-pointseven");
    }
})
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the jQuery code above so that the class gets added only at a place where is no content child elements.

Comment: You need to use a `$('.theclass').each()` loop. Inside the function you can use `$(this)` to refer to the current element.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0356bnd2/

Comment: @Chris G This looks good, thanks for the help but let say if I want to add class inside img tag. Can I use something like this  `$(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");`

Comment: img tag is beneath the `<figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">` line

Comment: This line `<img src="" srcset="">`

Comment: Yes, that should work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

No jquery needed.

```
if (
  document.querySelector('.featured-block__title > *').length === 0 &&
  document.querySelector('.featured-block__tag > *').length === 0
) {
  // add class here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't seem to work as the class which I want to add is getting added everywhere.

Comment: Then you need more specific selectors.

Comment: `.img-fit` is used everywhere in the html document. Is there any way we can target only specific `img-fit` ?

Comment: Ah I see what you are asking. One min.

Comment: I think your example is off. Where you have your comment about where the class should go, that div has content. Empty img element.

Comment: `<h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title"></h1>  // No content
 <h1 class="featured-block__tag"></h1>  // No content` It doesn't have any content, so the place where I have added a comment (`// It should be added here only`)should have added class when the page will load.

Comment: I think, I didn't explain the question properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189841/discussion-between-geuis-and-flash).

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon It may be the way you're trying to test if it's empty. Try this:

```
// Checks if div is empty, Uses trim to prevent unwanted spaces
if ( $.trim( $('.featured-block__title').text() ).length == 0 ) {
   // If empty add class to element
   $(".img-fit").addClass("opacity-pointseven");
}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the parent item and only query within that element. As it stands, each of your queries is applied to the entire document.

You probably want to use the `each()` method to loop over the sections and only query within the section by using the `this` parameter. Something like this:

```js
$('.featured-block__item').each(function() {
  if ($(".featured-block__title", this).is(":empty") && $(".featured-block__tag", this).is(":empty")) {
    $(this).find(".img-fit").addClass("opacity-pointseven")
  }
})
```

```css
.img-fit.opacity-pointseven {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured-block">
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">
            <img class="default-opacity" src="" data-fallback-img="" alt="">
         </figure>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">
            <img class="default-opacity" src="" data-fallback-img="" alt="">
         </figure>
      </div>
   </a>
   <!-- -->
   <a href="/149553/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">  // It should be added here only
            <img src="" srcset="">      
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title"></h1>
            // No content
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"></h1>
            // No content
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">   
            <img src="" 
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h1>
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Let say if I want to add class inside img tag. Can I use something like this `$(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");`

Comment: img tag is beneath the `<figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">` line

Comment: This line `<img src="" srcset="">`

Comment: That's right - if you wanted to add the class to the img tag itself, you would use `$(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven")`

Comment: Also, if we want to style it `$(this).find(".img-fit img").style.opacity = "0.7 !important";` can we use like that ? Is it correct ?

Comment: This is outside of the scope of your original question, but the normal way to apply styles in jQuery is to use the `css` helper. http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value